# StructureFareRulesRQ Parse Failure - Visual Studio Web Reference Naming Convention Error?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, sabre

I'm trying to call the StructureFareRulesRQ API from Sabre but its seems as though this API is different than the rest of the Sabre APIs. After adding the wsdl file to my project, I am expecting the Web Service call method to be named something like StructureFareRulesRQService but that doesn't exist. Instead I get StructureFareRulesRQ as the actual service and StructureFareRulesRQ1 as the wrapper class for the XML message. As the wrapper class has the wrong name, when it gets serialized, it creates a bogus XML message (see below).

I know I can probably dig through the reference.cs file and do a find/replace, but I'm concerned that doing that will require me to do the same thing whenever a new version comes online. Has anyone else run into this, or am I going nuts?

Example XML Payload which returns a "Error ErrorCode="009400" ErrorMessage="PARSE FAILURE - INVALID REQUEST" response from Sabre:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<StructureFareRulesRQ1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="USD" BuyingDate="2019-05-21T13:46:00" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07">
    <PassengerTypes>
      <PassengerType Code="ADT" />
    </PassengerTypes>
    <ReturnAllData />
  </PriceRequestInformation>
  <AirItinerary xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07">
    <OriginDestinationOptions>
      <OriginDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment SegmentType="A" DepartureDate="2019-08-17T17:35:00" BookingDate="2019-05-21T13:46:00" RealReservationStatus="SS">
          <DepartureAirport LocationCode="ORD" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="HEL" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="AY" />
          <OperatingAirline Code="AY" />
        </FlightSegment>
        <PaxTypeInformation FareBasisCode="IFLE2US2" PassengerType="ADT" FareComponentNumber="0" />
      </OriginDestinationOption>
      <OriginDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment SegmentType="A" DepartureDate="2019-08-18T13:25:00" BookingDate="2019-05-21T13:46:00" RealReservationStatus="SS">
          <DepartureAirport LocationCode="HEL" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="SVO" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="AY" />
          <OperatingAirline Code="SU" />
        </FlightSegment>
        <PaxTypeInformation FareBasisCode="IFLE2US2" PassengerType="ADT" FareComponentNumber="0" />
      </OriginDestinationOption>
      <OriginDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment SegmentType="A" DepartureDate="2019-08-29T10:40:00" BookingDate="2019-05-21T13:46:00" RealReservationStatus="SS">
          <DepartureAirport LocationCode="SVO" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="HEL" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="AY" />
          <OperatingAirline Code="SU" />
        </FlightSegment>
        <PaxTypeInformation FareBasisCode="IFLE2US2" PassengerType="ADT" FareComponentNumber="0" />
      </OriginDestinationOption>
      <OriginDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment SegmentType="A" DepartureDate="2019-08-29T13:55:00" BookingDate="2019-05-21T13:46:00" RealReservationStatus="SS">
          <DepartureAirport LocationCode="HEL" />
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ORD" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="AY" />
          <OperatingAirline Code="AY" />
        </FlightSegment>
        <PaxTypeInformation FareBasisCode="IFLE2US2" PassengerType="ADT" FareComponentNumber="0" />
      </OriginDestinationOption>
    </OriginDestinationOptions>
  </AirItinerary>
</StructureFareRulesRQ1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think StructureFareRulesRQ1 must be StructureFareRulesRQ. 
https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/utility/get_structured_fare_rules